# How to create a string of variable length with character X in C

Tags: c, string, loops, initialization

I am new to C and am having some troubles with strings. How do I create a string of variable length containing a specified character in C? This is what I have tried but I get a compiler error:

```
int  cLen     = 8    /* Specified Length    */ 
char chr      = 'a'; /* Specified Character */
char outStr[cLen];
int  tmp      = 0;
while (tmp < cLen-1)
  outStr[tmp++] = chr;

outStr[cLen-1] = '\0';

/* outStr = "aaaaaaaa" */
```

Comment: You really need to include which compiler error you're getting. Don't make us guess!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try:

```
char *str = malloc(cLen + 1);
memset(str, 'a', cLen);
str[cLen] = '\0';
```

(edited to properly terminate the string with '\0')

Comment: Except that doesn't create a valid string, no termination.

Comment: @unwind Good call, just noticed.

Comment: '\0' instead of 0 would make it perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Strings in C might not be as flexible as you want, on the first look.

What you did with "char outStr[]" was to indicate you'd like a pointer to char, that can be iterated with array syntax... it creates no actual storage for the characters, because you never mentioned how many you would like to store.

In C you can have the storage decoupled from these special variables, called pointers. The example of wanting a variable length string is actually a good example of why would you want that: *I want an entity that holds knowledge of where the storage is at; I want methods to allow me to change the storage size.*

So, you prepare yourself to deal with dynamic memory allocation by including

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

declare a pointer to chars by

```
char *cpString;
```

you ask for an allocation of "n" chars with

```
cpString=malloc(n*sizeof(char));
```

Now you can **strcat, printf**, whatever you want to do with a string that has n-1 charaters (because it must be null terminated).
Specifically, you can now initialize your string with

```
memset(cpString,X,n-1);
cpString[n]=0;
```

which creates a XXXX...XXX\0 string, of n-1 characters.

When you want to change cpString storage size, here's the tricky part, you need to **free** the allocated memory before you request for a new storage allocation

```
if (cpString !=0)
{
 free(cpString);
 cpString=0;
}
cpString=malloc(n*sizeof(char));
```

otherwise the dynamic memory storage area (called a "heap") is left with an un-reclaimable piece of the old n size.

There are better allocators, that don't need free(), but I better leave you studying and practicing with malloc() free() usage.

Comment: `sizeof(char)`, by definition, is always 1 because `sizeof` and `size_t` are always in terms of `char`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use `strncat()`, strings are just character arrays so do the assignment directly character by character:

```
void repeated_string(char *out, size_t len, char v)
{
  for(; len > 0; --len)
    *out++ = v;
  *out = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Could you look at my edited code and tell me why it give a different compile error?

Comment: And there's this signature also `for(; len-- > 0;) ;`, but ugly yeah

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code:

1) the length is (probably) not what you're expecting. You have:

```
int cLen = 8; /* Specified Length */
```

Presumably you want a string of length 8. Because you have to add a NULL terminator, you're only getting a string of length 7 right now. If that's what you want you should just update your comment to make that clear:

```
int cLen = 9; /* Specified Length (8) + 1 for NULL */
```

2) you're not assigning the char correctly:

```
char chr = "a";
```

is not right. Characters are specified with a single quote:

```
char chr = 'a';
```

After that your code should work.